# Help plotting or evaluating confluent hypergeometric function and a Gamma function, both with imaginary values

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex

I have this *confluent hypergeometric function*

$
    \begin{equation}
    _{1}F_{1}\left( \frac{i}{2}x,1,ix \right)
    \end{equation}$

and this *gamma function*

$
    \begin{equation}
    \Gamma\left( 1-ix \right)
    \end{equation}
$

as you can see both function have *imaginary parameters*, in the *Mathematica* webpage only I found plot examples with real parameters.

**Wow can get the real part of this two functions so I can plot them?**

Comment: You really should make more effort next time you ask a question. Repeatedly you show no attempts to search the documentation, no formatted code of your own. It's very discouraging to see questions that ask for big tasks but show little effort. If you expect to inspire anybody to **volunteer their time to look at your problem**, then start by doing your part.

Answer (score 2):

[`Re[z]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) gives the real part of the complex number z.

```
Re[Hypergeometric1F1[(I x)/2, 1, I x]]
```

To [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) both,

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Re /@ {
    Hypergeometric1F1[(I x)/2, 1, I x],
    Gamma[1 - I x]
    }
  ]
 , {x, -6, 6}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sub>Code and plots done in *Mathemathica 11.2* on Win7</sub>